# Adding image from url to listview item

Tags: c#, winforms

I used picturebox  function Load pictureBox1.Load(linkSlike); , but now i want to add this picture to listview item instead and I am not sure how to load it from url.

```
for (int j = 0; j < Stan.listaStanova.Count; j++)
        {
                         listView1.Items.Add(Stan.listaStanova[j].ToString(),Stan.listaStanova[j].linkSlike);                         
        }
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly! - You add it to an ImageList and set the LargeImageList f the ilstview. Note the sizes must all be the same ans <= 256x256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 - Download the Image

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(Stan.listaStanova[j].linkSlike);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
ms.Dispose();
```

Step 2 - Add the image to an image list

```
ImageList Imagelist = new ImageList(); // SHOULD BE DECLARED AT FORM LEVEL
imagelist.Images.Add(img);
```

Step 3 - Assign List View to Image List

```
listView1.LargeImageList = Imagelist;
listView1.SmallImageList = Imagelist;
```

Step 4 - For the Given List View Item (Let's Say the First One, Assign the ImageIndex).  The ImageIndex refers to the position in the array to find the image in the list view's image list property.  In this example, we're saying for the listview's first item, assign the index of the first image.

```
listView1.Items[0].ImageIndex = 0;
```

Putting it all together (again image list should be declared at form level so not declared in the example:

```
listView1.LargeImageList = Imagelist;
listView1.SmallImageList = Imagelist;

for (int j = 0; j < Stan.listaStanova.Count; j++)
{

     WebClient wc = new WebClient();
     byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(Stan.listaStanova[j].linkSlike);
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
     System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
     imagelist.Images.Add(img);
     ms.Dispose();

     // IN THIS CASE, WE'RE ASSUMING EACH LIST ITEM HAS A DISTINCT IMAGE
     // SO COUNT OF IMAGE COLLECTION IS SAME AS LISTVIEWITEMCOLLECTION
     // SO IMAGEINDEX PROPERTY IS ALWAYS THE J
     listView1.Items.Add(Stan.listaStanova[j].ToString(),j);                         
}
```

Comment: `MemoryStream` should be declared in a `Using` block (or Disposed anyway). Then, you could just:  `imagelist.Images.Add(new Bitmap(ms));`, since one of the possible sources for a `Bitmap` is a `Stream` (i.e `Image.FromStream(ms)` is not necessary).

Comment: i added the dispose @Jimi